# How do I get the full site button on jQuery Mobile site to work correctly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, jquery-mobile

I designed a webpage and a mobile version of the same page (using jQuery Mobile).

I have javascript code that detects if the user is using a mobile device, and then redirects to the mobile site (mobile.html).

But when the user tries to go from the mobile site to the desktop or full site it brings up the page, but doesn't look right... it's kind of zoomed in and displaced when looking on a Mobile Device.

```
************The Javascript to detect mobile device************

var mobile = (/iphone|ipad|ipod|android|blackberry|mini|windows\sce|palm/i.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase()));  
 if (mobile) { 
    document.location = "http://www.somedomain.com/mobile.html";  }
 }  




************jQuery Mobile button for Full Site ***************

<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
        <li>
            <a href="http://www.somdomain.com/?view=full">Full Site</a>
        </li>
</ul>
```

How do I get the redirect to the full site to look like it should on the mobile device?

Comment: Hi mate! Could you show a screenshot?

Comment: I don't have a screenshot sorry... But you can try the site out.. it's www.bobbyaudley.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Obviously you'll go back to the mobile website because it will run your detection script and redirect you straight back. You need to use techniques to avoid this.

You need to TELL the full site you just came from the mobile website and DO NOT want to go back.

Some examples for on the full site:

- check if **view** is set to '**full**'. If *true*, set a cookie or a php session to avoid running the detection script.
- check if the **referrer** is the mobile website. If *true*, dont run the detection script.

Hope this gets you on your way.

Comment: Thank you soooo much! The actual code I used that worked is below.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to Gillian Lo-Wong, I was able to get the following code to work for me...

home.html

```
function urlParam(name){
            var results = new RegExp('[\\?&amp;]' + name + '=([^&amp;#]*)').exec(window.location.href);
            if(results)
                return results[1] || 0;
            else
                return '';
        }

        if(urlParam('view') == 'full'){ 
        }
        if(urlParam('view') == ''){
            // <![CDATA[
            var mobile = (/iphone|ipad|ipod|android|blackberry|mini|windows\sce|palm/i.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase()));  
            if (mobile) { 
                    document.location = "http://www.mysite.com/mobile.html";  
            }  
            // ]]>
        }
```

and the mobile.html code

```
<a href="http://www.mysite.com?view=full" data-ajax="false">Full Site</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try adding `rel="external"` to the `<a>` link leading to your desktop page:

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
    <li>
        <a href="http://www.somdomain.com/?view=full" rel="external">Full Site</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

This will disable the Ajax navigation and will make sure to refresh the page, erasing the data transforming your desktop page into a mobile page.

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: I tried that, and when you click that link, it just seems to refresh the page and bring back the mobile site.

Comment: I have also tried putting `<a href="http://www.somdomain.com/?view=full" data-ajax="false">Full Site</a>` but it does the same thing, it reloads the mobile page.

Comment: Is there another way to get the AJAX not to load the new site?